# Comparing a proportion to a 'mean' proportion. Which test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose there are 24 factories who all fabricate the same product with a certain percentage of that product being faulty. We have a table of data:

Factory, Produced, Faulty

F1, 212, 31

F2, 1021, 145

…, …, …

F24, 480, 40

Now I want to check factory F1 has a different proportion of faulty product than the average (!!) proportion of the other factories. With 2 factories I could make a 2 sample proportion test /  CHi^2 work, but now I am not interested in the difference between say F3 and F17, I just want to know, if F2 through F24 is considered, does F1 perform worse?

I was thinking that I could do a 2 sample proportion test, where F2 through F24 could be considered one giant factory (summing the non-faulty products and faulty products as a set to test against the set of non faulty products from F1 and faulty products from F1).

But I want to be sure. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clarifying whether the data arises from random sampling or not.

You can check out the following images for a more detail description.

[image: Chi-Square Test]

[image: Analysis of Variance (ANOVA)]